# Ricksahw Graph as 'NXY' (one x multiple y) from array possible?

Tags: charts, rickshaw

Im using shutterstock rickshaw [chart](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/) library to visualize some sensordata via ajax-php-sql.

In all examples, rickshaw relies on data for the series in the form

```
[ [ { x: xval1, y: yval1}, { x: xval2, y: yval2}, ...] 
  [ { x: xval1, y: yvalS2_1}, { x: xval2, y: yvalS2_2}, ...]
]
```

which I find a bit tedious compared to e.g. xmgrace's 'nxy' mode:
one x-column, n y-columns - which is exactly what I get from the sql query (because my sensors are sampled at identic timestamps).

So the question would be is it possible to privide rickshaw's data input always the same x-data vector and individual y-data vectors, held in an array?

Thank You!
Alex